# how to translate linq groupjoin to lambda groupjoin

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Because i need to do some filter condition feature ,I'm now want to translate a linq query to the lambda expression object.

linq code:

```
var query = from chlsynclog in oaPtDbContext.TableChlSyncLog

                        join mealchl in oaPtDbContext.TableMealChl on new { X1 = chlsynclog.Mealid, Y1 = chlsynclog.Chid } equals new { X1 = mealchl.Mealid, Y1 = mealchl.Chid }
                        into mealchlGroup
                        from mealchlGroupItem in mealchlGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                        join service in oaPtDbContext.TableService on mealchlGroupItem.Sid equals service.Sid
                        into serviceGroup
                        from serviceGroupItem in serviceGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                        join channel in oaPtDbContext.TableChannel on chlsynclog.Chid equals channel.Chid
                        into channelGroup
                        from channelGroupItem in channelGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                        join area in oaPtDbContext.TableArea on chlsynclog.Areaid equals area.Areaid
                        into areaGroup
                        from areaGroupItem in areaGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                        select new
                        {
                            chlsynclog.Id,
                            chlsynclog.Handset,
                            mealchlGroupItem.Mealname,
                            areaGroupItem.Proname,
                            areaGroupItem.Cityname,
                            chlsynclogType= GetChlsynclogType(chlsynclog.Type),
                            statusName=GetStatusName(chlsynclog.Statusid),
                            channelGroupItem.Chname,
                            syncTime=chlsynclog.Synctime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                        };
```

and I began to do this work,after i translated to the third

> join

```
var testQuery =

                oaPtDbContext.TableChlSyncLog

                .GroupJoin(oaPtDbContext.TableMealChl,
                (chlsynclog) => new
                {
                    X1 = chlsynclog.Mealid,
                    X2 = chlsynclog.Chid
                },
                (mealchl) => new
                {
                    X1 = mealchl.Mealid,
                    X2 = mealchl.Chid
                },
                (x, y) => new
                {
                    X = x,
                    Y = y
                })
                .SelectMany(temp0 => temp0.Y.DefaultIfEmpty())

                .GroupJoin(oaPtDbContext.TableService,
                mealchl => mealchl.Sid,
                service => service.Sid,
                (x, y) => new { X = x, Y = y })
                .SelectMany(temp0 => temp0.Y.DefaultIfEmpty())

                .GroupJoin(oaPtDbContext.TableChannel,)

                ;
```

> .GroupJoin(oaPtDbContext.TableChannel,)

The Second parameter just get the previous type's object TableService,
but i need the parameter should be the TableCholSynclog's Chid.
So here I have no idea to go on this work.
And I use the query.Expression.ToString() to see the expression:

```
<>h__TransparentIdentifier3.<>h__TransparentIdentifier2.<>h__TransparentIdentifier1.<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.chlsynclog.Chid
```

The sourcecode can do this but i can not !

So,How to write my lambda expression ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want lambda?

```
var query = oaPtDbContext.TableChlSyncLog.GroupJoin(
                              oaPtDbContext.TableMealChl,
                              chlsynclog => new
                                 {
                                    X1 = chlsynclog.Mealid,
                                    Y1 = chlsynclog.Chid
                                 },
                              mealchl => new
                                 {
                                    X1 = mealchl.Mealid,
                                    Y1 = mealchl.Chid
                                 },
                              (chlsynclog, mealchlGroup) => new
                                 {
                                    chlsynclog,
                                    mealchlGroup
                                 })
                           .SelectMany(
                              @t => mealchlGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                              (@t, mealchlGroupItem) => new
                                 {
                                    @t,
                                    mealchlGroupItem
                                 })
                           .GroupJoin(
                              oaPtDbContext.TableService,
                              @t => mealchlGroupItem.Sid,
                              service => service.Sid,
                              (@t, serviceGroup) => new
                                 {
                                    @t,
                                    serviceGroup
                                 })
                           .SelectMany(
                              @t => serviceGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                              (@t, serviceGroupItem) => new
                                 {
                                    @t,
                                    serviceGroupItem
                                 })
                           .GroupJoin(
                              oaPtDbContext.TableChannel,
                              @t => chlsynclog.Chid,
                              channel => channel.Chid,
                              (@t, channelGroup) => new
                                 {
                                    @t,
                                    channelGroup
                                 })
                           .SelectMany(
                              @t => channelGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                              (@t, channelGroupItem) => new
                                 {
                                    @t,
                                    channelGroupItem
                                 })
                           .GroupJoin(
                              oaPtDbContext.TableArea,
                              @t => chlsynclog.Areaid,
                              area => area.Areaid,
                              (@t, areaGroup) => new
                                 {
                                    @t,
                                    areaGroup
                                 })
                           .SelectMany(
                              @t => areaGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                              (@t, areaGroupItem) => new
                                 {
                                    chlsynclog.Id,
                                    chlsynclog.Handset,
                                    mealchlGroupItem.Mealname,
                                    areaGroupItem.Proname,
                                    areaGroupItem.Cityname,
                                    chlsynclogType = GetChlsynclogType(chlsynclog.Type),
                                    statusName = GetStatusName(chlsynclog.Statusid),
                                    channelGroupItem.Chname,
                                    syncTime = chlsynclog.Synctime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                                 });
```

**Note** : This was just Resharpers, `Convert Linq to chain method` feature. you can probably make this a loooot prettier.

Comment: Wow!That's it! Can you tell me that where to retrieve the "@t" featrure ?

Comment: @Eric do you mean the feature to convert it to a linq chain method ? this is resharper . https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw5LbWBRDCARIsALAbcOeWubUQPxrlACHPhvfXJBPLSSZhRwn5tvrAfdOhx-XigqKBanb2MUIaApu9EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds.ds&dclid=CM_WnIeMtNoCFVUbvAodB2MDXA

Comment: If you are wondering what the @t is, i think its just resharper being extra cautious , i think you can remove the @ all together, and name them properly

Comment: Just wonder the "@t" feature in .net platform.Otherwise, I found another program to convert lambda from linq : [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).And do you have something suggest for me to use linq to make the fliter feature , now i can do this just use the lambda's "Where" method to do this.

Comment: @ usually just signifies that it is a variable instead of a reserved word. also i didnt know linqpad did that, nice to know. the wy i converted this was resharper. just right clicked and chose linq to chain method